# addEventListener works on code pen but not on visual studio code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do alert("clicked") when a button is pressed but I can't get it to work on visual studio code, it only works on codepen. I run the index.html in visual studio code using an extension called open in browser.

I tried copying the codes to codepen and it worked

```html
<html>
    <head>       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Random dog Pictures</h1>
            <img id = "photo" src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/68/6d/6f/686d6fc9d01def6b6f63acded53479bc.jpg" alt = "">
            <button id = "btn">Get Random Dog Photo!!!</button>
        </div>
        <script src="randomDogPicture.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

I expected it to display "clicked" but it doesn't do anything when I click the button.

Comment: Works fine for me. Where are you including the JavaScript in the document?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: It is saved all in the same folder, the problem is when I comment all the codes in the javascript and replace it with 'alert("clicked")' it works when I refresh the page, but I want to bind it with a button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your script is running before the DOM is fully loaded. You can either place your code at the bottom of the body or wrap your code with `DOMContentLoaded`:

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert("clicked");
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Random dog Pictures</h1>
    <img id = "photo" src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/68/6d/6f/686d6fc9d01def6b6f63acded53479bc.jpg" alt = "">
    <button id = "btn">Get Random Dog Photo!!!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works sir, by the way do I have to put all my event listeners in the html file or there's a way to put it in the javascript file?

Comment: @Dhenz, not necessarily all your code has to be inside the event, but it is good practice:)

Comment: If the issue is that the element doesn't exist yet, please vote to close as a duplicate of the canonical; this exact question has been asked so many times before, there's no need for yet another answer saying the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the default action (reloading the page) by doing this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      alert("clicked");
    });
  });
```

I'm not sure if it helps but give it a try

Comment: I'm not pro in js so plz dont downvote if it doesnt help, thanks

Comment: Works too sir.  I'm new to programming thanks for helping out